# What is the syntax to access the volume_id and instance_id of an ec2_instance dynamically in the new Terraform 1.3.7 version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We have a requirement in our environment to get the volume_id details based on the number of instances created dynamically. The instances are created based on the '**count**' value. We usually create three instance of an aws_instance.
**One more important thing is it is not able to create the ebs volume itself , I don't see the volume in the plan file.**

```
#Var.tf
variable "ec2_count" {
  default = "1"
}
    
variable "create_ec2_data_volume" {
  default = "false"
}
```

```
#Main.tf
resource aws_instance ec2_instance {
  count = var.ec2_count
  ami = var.ami_id
  instance_type = var.instance_type
}
        
resource aws_ebs_volume example_volume {
  count = "${var.create_ec2_data_volume == 0 ? var.ldp_count : 0}"
  availability_zone = element(aws_instance.ec2_instance.*.availability_zone, count.index)
  type = var.ebs_volume_type
  size = var.ec2_vol_size
    
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
    
  tags = {
     Name = "ec2-${var.owner}-${count.index}-volume"
     Owner = var.owner
     Environment = var.environment
  }
}
    
resource aws_volume_attachment attach_example_volume {
  depends_on = [aws_ebs_volume.example_volume]
  count = var.ldp_count
  device_name = "/dev/${var.device_name}"
  volume_id = aws_ebs_volume.example_volume[count.index].id
  instance_id = aws_instance.ec2_instance[count.index].id
}
```

I pushed the above code and getting below error, Please check and let me know what needs to be changed in the code.

```
Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on modules/developer/ec2/main.tf line 143, in resource "aws_volume_attachment" "attach_example_volume":
        │  143:   volume_id = aws_ebs_volume.example_volume[count.index].id
│   
├────────────────
│     │ aws_ebs_volume.example_volume is empty tuple
│     │ count.index is 0
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the
│ collection has no elements.
```

Comment: Value for the `create_ec2_data_volume` is set to `false` and it is its default value which means that the volume will not be created because of the `count = "${var.create_ec2_data_volume == 0 ? var.ldp_count : 0}"` line.

Comment: @MarkoE here in this code count = "${var.create_ec2_data_volume == 0 ? var.ldp_count : 0}", if the condition is true then it will create ldp_count instances of ebs_volume resource if not it will create '0' instances of ebs_volume resource. And moreover I tried by changing the value to true also but it is not working. It is giving the same above error.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems with the current code. In the `var.tf` file, the default value for the number of EC2 instances is quoted, which means it would be treated as a string (instead of a number). The same applies to the `create_ec2_data_volume` which should be of type `bool` and currently it is of type `string`. To fix this, change the `ec2_count` and `create_ec2_data_volume` variables to be of type `number` and `bool` respectively:

```
variable "ec2_count" {
  type    = number
  default = 1
}

variable "create_ec2_data_volume" {
  type    = bool
  default = false
}
```

Additionally, the `create_ec2_data_volume` has a default value of `false`, which means the volume will never get created unless you override the default value. You can do that by using `terraform.tfvars` file or providing the value on the CLI. If you decide to use the `terraform.tfvars` file, you need to add this line:

```
create_ec2_data_volume = true
```

If you want to provide the value when calling terraform commands, you need to do the following:

```bash
terraform plan -var="create_ec2_data_volume=true"
terraform apply -var="create_ec2_data_volume=true"
```

Finally, the code also needs a bit of change:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
    count         = var.ec2_count
    ami           = var.ami_id
    instance_type = var.instance_type
}
    
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "example_volume" {
  count = var.create_ec2_data_volume ? var.ldp_count : 0
  availability_zone = element(aws_instance.ec2_instance.*.availability_zone, count.index)
  type = var.ebs_volume_type
  size = var.ec2_vol_size

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "ec2-${var.owner}-${count.index}-volume"
    Owner = var.owner
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "attach_example_volume" {
  count       = var.create_ec2_data_volume ? var.ldp_count : 0
  device_name = "/dev/${var.device_name}"
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.example_volume[count.index].id
  instance_id = aws_instance.ec2_instance[count.index].id
}
```

By adding the same conditional logic to the `aws_volume_attachment` resource, you will avoid the error you have currently when the `create_ec2_data_volume` variable value is set to `false`.

Comment: This was resolved by changing the count = "${var.create_ec2_data_volume == 0 ? var.ldp_count : 0}" to count = "${var.create_ec2_data_volume == false ? var.ldp_count : 0}" i,e. using false instead of zero. Thanks all for the help!